# PCLCrypto.dll runtime error

Tags: xamarin, md5

Xamarin, Portable multiplatform solution, portable project section

For MD5 hashing I create class md5. add to project referece PCLCrypto.dll.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PCLCrypto;
using static PCLCrypto.WinRTCrypto;


namespace WCHSBMobile
{
    public static class md5
    {
        public static string GetMD5hash(string data)
        {
            //string result = data;
            IHashAlgorithmProvider algoProv = PCLCrypto.WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5);
            byte[] dataB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] dataHash = algoProv.HashData(dataB);
            var hex = new StringBuilder(dataHash.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in dataHash)
            {
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            }
            return hex.ToString();
            //return result;
        }

    }
}
```

When testing on android on this line I get Runtime error          IHashAlgorithmProvider algoProv = PCLCrypto.WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5); I get the error
PCLCrypto.NotImplementedByReferenceAssemblyException: This is a reference assembly and does not contain implementation. Be sure to install the PCLCrypto package into your application so the platform implementation assembly will be used at runtime.
What should I do? Can you advice me any solution?
Thank you

Comment: Did you add the PCLCrypto Nuget package to your Android specific project? You have to add PCLCrypto to the PCL AND each platform because it has to use platform specific code.

Comment: I just encountered the same error today with a project that built fine before updating VS.
And yes, I have PCLCrypto in all projects.

Comment: Pretty strange, after uninstalling the App from the device and again deploying it it worked

Comment: Thanks,it helped a lot

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue in a Xamarin app. As suggested in the comments by dylan-s and thomas, try the following steps:

- Uninstall the app
- Enusure the PCLCrypto Nuget package is installed in the Android project as well as the portable project.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with a Xamarin Android project using AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.SQS. Both are in the PCL but also needed to to add both to the Android project.

Comment: Thanks! The important thing was, that the Library has to be in the Portable Project where it is used AND also in the Main project itself - also without any Xamarin Projects

Answer (score 4):

Besides the steps given by J. Andrew Laughlin, what worked for me was to rebuild the app in Xamarin Studio, or clean the app and build it again.

Comment: Same here. Cleaning the solution in VS helped.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue when the package is only installed in the portable class library. The method seems to find the MAC libraries event in Android run which are obviously absent. Hence install it in the PCL and the Android project. The android project libraries will override during the build and you won't have any runtime errors.